# Trying to auto-increment counter during edit in ASP.NET Core Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to auto-increment `TimesModified` by 1 every time when `Edit` method is run.

When I use the following code, only `TimesModified` gets incremented but other parameters do not change (even though I'm changing let's say `Age`):

[image]

When I use the other version of code, everything else can be changed/updated but `TimesModified` doesn't get incremented:

[image]

I also tried this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,Age,City,Department,HiredDate,FiredDate,TimesModified")] Employee employee)
{
        if (id != employee.ID)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
  
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {                    
                _context.Update(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                _context.Update(employee.TimesModified++);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
}
```

And I get this error:

[image]

Any suggestions?

**1st suggestion** is giving following error:

[image]

**2nd suggestion** has no errors but when I change anything like Age for example, it resets back to original(prior to edit) value: (However TimesModified gets incremented ok)
[image]

[image]

[image]

**3rd suggestion** my final SOLUTION!!!

added extra input field inside Edit View

[image]

Inside Edit Action , doing update in 2 steps: Save input , increment, Save again.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**3rd suggestion** my final SOLUTION!!!

added extra input field inside Edit View
[image]

Inside Edit Action , doing update in 2 steps: Save input , increment, Save again.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var employee =  await _context.Employees
               .Where(e => e.Id == employee.Id) 
                .FisrstOrDefaultAsync();

employee.TimesModified+= 1;
_context.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
//or _context.Entry(employee).Property(t=>t.TimesModified).IsModified = true;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Sergey I edited my question with your suggestion. I'm not sure what happens there but looks like when updating any value (Age for example), it gets lost in the process.  So the result of my Age edit from 33 to 44 -> becomes Age still 33 and counter TimesModified goes up by 1.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think there is concurrency issue. Because Value like Age is coming from the user or Form inside the View, while TimesModified (integer like 1 or 2)  coming from the database, and gets processed at the same time.

Comment: Also Timestamp (ModifiedDate) gets updated at the same time.

Comment: OMG I kinda made it work but its really weird. I had to add another input field for this TimesModified property inside Edit View and inside Edit action first I SaveChanges that are coming from the View( Age for example) and then I pull the same record/entity from the DB and then increment TimesModified by 1 and then SaveChanges again. For the extra added "TimesModified" input field I just added hidden type in order to find it from the user. See my final edit above...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetching the whole entity, just query the TimesModified.

Eg

```
var tm = _context.Employees.Select(e => e.Id == employee.Id).Select(e => e.TimesModified).First();

employee.TimesModified = tm + 1;
_context.Update(employee);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: when i did this its underlining TimesModified with this error:
CS1061: "bool" does not contain a definition for "TimesModified" and no accessible extension method "TimesModified" accepting a first argument of type "bool" could be found

Comment: Then you're calling the .TimesModified on the wrong variable.  You're doing something like `var b = false; b.TimesModified = 2;`.